# After $2013$ such transformations, how many number $2013$ are there on the line if the given numbers are $1$ and $1000$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

Several natural numbers are given on a line, we perform a transformation as follow:for every pair of consecutive integers on the line, write sum of those two numbers in the middle of them. After $2013$ such transformations, how many number $2013$ are there on the line if:

a. The given numbers are $1$ and $1000$?

b. The given numbers are $1,2,3,\dots,1000$?

My Progress for part a , I think the answer is $2$ .

Note that any number in this transformation will be of the form $1\cdot x + y\cdot 1000$.

Let us for simplicity, express the numbers in the transformation in the form $(x,y)$ where, $(x,y)$ represents  $1\cdot x + y \cdot 1000$ .  for example, $2001=(1,2)$.

Consider the following image:
[image]

Define '$n-$line' as the $n^{\text{th}}$ transformation row .

**Observation $1$**:  we cannot have $2$ equal  $(x,y)$ in any line [ I don't have a proof for it but it looks very true and probably can be proved by induction ( though I was not able to )] .

**Observation $2$** : we can only have $(x,0)$ or $(0,x)$  if $x \ne 1$ [ this is true ]

Note that $2013= (2013,0),(1013,1), (13,2)$.

Now by observation $2$, we get that $(1013,1)$ and $(13,2)$ are the only solutions that can appear.

and by observation $1$, we get that the above solutions are uniques .

So, $2$ is the answer for part a [ If observation 1 is correct ]

Moreover, I got $2$ more observations.

**Observation $3$**: In any line , the numbers with same $x$-coordinate ( or the same $y$- coordinate )are arranged in either strictly increasing order or strictly decreasing order in the sequence. Also the $y-$coordinates are in an AP

**Observation $4$**: Note that coordinates are mirror image .

To explain it more nicely look at the $3$-line. Observe the coordinates of  $2^{\text{nd}}$ number from the left and the $2^{\text{nd}}$ number from the right. The coordinates are reflected !

for example look at the 3-line , we have the number $(1,1)$ then $(1,2)$ and then $(1,3)$ .[Note that the $y $-coordinates are in an AP with $d=1$]

One can see the essence of Observation $3$ after constructing the $5^{\text{th}}$ transformation or so.

Please give hints if possible and do try this beautiful problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Hint*: [Farey sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farey_sequence).

Comment: oh, I didn't know that like this existed and interestingly my 2nd line is the (almost ) the same as F_1 ( by observation 1 )  but still how does it help me in observation 2 and 3 ?

Comment: read this.. it might be helpful

Comment: This is VNMO 2013 P4
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h515934p2921019

Comment: @Anand I see . it was actually in a2048's mock

Comment: Oh okay .....